# Create a notification popup animated in a specific way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I go about making the following animation for my form submissions?

(I figured instead of typing it, I would create a visual.)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's Andy's idea refined with horizontal centering.

HTML:

```
<form><div id="message"></div>
   <input> Label 1<br/><br/>
   <input> Label 2<br/><br>
   <textarea>Larger text area</textarea><br/><br/>
   <textarea>And another</textarea><br/><br/>
<button type="button">Submit</button>
```

​

CSS:

```
form { 
   position:relative; 
   width:500px;}
#message { 
   position:absolute;
   display:none;
   height:100px;
   width:200px;
   border: 1px gray solid;
   background-color:lime;
   font-size: 1.4em;
   line-height:100px;
   text-align:center;
   border-radius: 5px;
   bottom: 100px;}
```

​

Centering function:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.extend({
    center: function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var left = ($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2;
            $(this).css({
                position: 'absolute',
                margin: 0,
                left: (left > 0 ? left : 0) + 'px'
            });
        });
    }
});})(jQuery);
```

Call center:

```
$("#message").center();
```

Click function:

```
$("button").click(function() {
var msg = $("#message");
msg.text("Item saved!")
msg.hide()
msg.stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow').animate({
    "bottom": "4px",
    "height": "17px",
    "font-size": "1em",
    "left": "80px",
    "line-height": "17px",
    "width": "100px"
}).delay(2000).fadeOut('slow').css({
    "height": "100px",
    "width": "200px",
    "font-size": "1.4em",
    "line-height": "100px",
    "bottom": "100px"
}).center();});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2qJfF/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZDkM/
This latest one does both horizontal and vertical centering.  Furthermore it figures out position of button being clicked so that animation follows the button appropriately.

Answer (score 10):

I've thrown together a proof of concept for you, using jsFiddle:

> **http://jsfiddle.net/kAhXd/1/** (animation now resets, click the submit button)

You'll need to take a good look at the CSS, but the important thing to note is the `<form>` element's position is set to *relative*, and the message element's position is set to *absolute*.  This is to ensure that the message element's position is always relative to the form element.

**HTML**

```
<form><div id="message"></div>
    <input> Label 1<br/><br/>
    <input> Label 2<br/><br>
    <textarea>Larger text area</textarea><br/><br/>
    <textarea>And another</textarea><br/><br/>
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>​
```

**CSS**

```
form { position:relative; width:500px; }
#message { 
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    border: 1px gray solid;
    background-color:lime;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    left: 150px;
    bottom:100px; 
    border-radius: 5px;
}    ​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var msg = $("#message");
    msg[0].style.cssText = "";
    msg.text("Item saved!");
    msg.fadeIn('slow').animate({
        "bottom": "3px",
        "height": "17px",
        "font-size": "1em",
        "left": "80px",
        "line-height": "17px",
        "width": "100px"
    });
});​
```

Comment: This is a great start, though, I was hoping to center the notification in the center of the vieport when it pops up.  Currently you have it positioned absolutely not realy taking into account where the view port is.. though it may be over kill to get it in center of view port.

Comment: +1. For the proof of concept, but more importantly for the handy site I've never heard of before.

Comment: Can you post some of the code here in your post as well? Great example.

Comment: @Roeland: It makes it more complicated, that's for sure, but it's still possible.  You would need to be sure of the exact positions of items - for instance, getting the offset position of the submit button and declaring that as the final position + x pixels to the left property for the final animation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery.  Here's the steps I would take to approach this:

1. Code the basic HTML to get started including the necessary `<form>` and `<input>` fields.
2. Create an empty div for the item saved notification. `<div id="item_saved">Item Saved!</div>` and have the default styling be `display:none`.
3. Add JavaScript to do form verification to make sure the inputs have what you're expecting.
4. In the form save code, I expect you'll be using [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).  In the success callback, call a function which makes changes to #item_saved.  Initially, change visibility of the element and apply a class which gives it the initial position in your second image.
5. Use the jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.  You'll want to have it change the position and the dimensions.  jQuery UI extends the animate function to provide additional capabilities: look at the [animate demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/).

**Update:** Edited to provide additional information and more directly address the question.